# How to diagnose this exception from Invoke-Sqlcmd?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, sqlps

I'm running the following command (smallest reproducible example I could come up with):

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd "select * from sys.databases"  | %{
    Invoke-Sqlcmd "select 1"     
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Could not find any resources appropriate for the
>   specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "pipeline.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly
>   "System.Management.Automation" at compile time, or that all the
>   satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Invoke-Sqlcmd "select * from sys.databases"  | %{
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], MissingManifestResourceException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailed,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Tired this:

- both with ISE and command line
- both elevated ("run as administrator") and not
- against SQL 2012 and SQL 2008
- from a Windows 8 and from Server 2008

In all cases the result is the same.

Why and how to diagnose?

Comment: I am trying to understand what is the significance of `select 1`. The first `Invoke-Sqlcmd` works for me, and I am able to pipe it to print database names. However, I see the same error on using `select 1`

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan I believe it's a combination of both. Select 1 is obviously working fine on it's own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've also noticed issues using invoke-sqlcmd to chain together invoke-sqlcmd commands via pipeline. A workaround which seems to address issue, save the output of first command to variable then pipe output to next invoke-sqlcmd call.

```
$databases = Invoke-Sqlcmd "select * from sys.databases"  
$databases | % { Invoke-Sqlcmd "select 1" }
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I ended up with. Looks like Invoke-Sqlcmd is not quite re-entrant, eh?

Comment: There are several other issues with invoke-sqlcmd. A more serious issue is around error handling where invoke-sqlcmd will quietly swallows errors. Use invoke-sqlcmd with caution: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/779320/invoke-sqlcmd-does-not-return-t-sql-errors

Comment: Yes, I've noticed some other issues as well.